# What shape would this make in Java?

Tags: java, graphics

Struggling drawing this out trying to derive the graphic it would create.  Some help would be appreciated.  Thanks to anyone that comments or helps, I'm stumped.

```
marker.forward(120);
marker.turnRight(45);
marker.forward(80);
market.turnLeft(90);
marker.forward(80);
marker.turnLeft(90);
marker.forward(80);
marker.turnLeft(90);
marker.forward(80);
```

Comment: And what did you got when you ran it?

Comment: I didn't run it, it's all on paper.

Comment: Why you do not draw it on the paper? I think that is not too hard...

Comment: I did man I want to verify I'm drawing it correctly..  I'm getting an odd flag shpae.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shape should look somthing like that:

[image]

It may look a little bit diffrent it is not the original size and I also draw it in paint.